# including zend module in php application

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter

I'm using Zend to include Google agenda in my php application (I use CodeIgniter as framework). But I have many warnings like :

```
Message: include_once(Zend/Gdata.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.
```

There is my directory list :

```
--dir1
       -- Zend
           -- Loader.php

/var/www/my_app
  --controllers
     -- calendar.php
```

In calendar.php, this is my path configuration

```
 require_once '../Zend/Loader.php';
```

The error occurs when these lines are executed :

```
require_once '.../Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
```

and especially it comes from the function which loads files in Loader.php :

```
  public static function loadFile($filename, $dirs = null, $once = false)
        { ........    
include_once $filename;  }
```

I tried to remove Zend so it can be in the same directory as the controller as suggested in many answers to this problem but it still not work. Could anyone help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To include files in PHP you have 2 options :

1) Define the full server path, like this :

```
/home/project/dir1/Zend/Gdata.php
```

2) Define the path from the file that is executed by apache/something else, like this with the dir1 :

```
dir1/Zend/Gdata.php
```

In a Zend project you can do this to be sure it will work :

```
include_once(APPLICATION_PATH."/../dir1/Zend/Gdata.php")
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. Actually it is a CodeIgniter project in which I include a Zend module.My problem occurs when this line is executed

Comment: Yes, it's because your path is not properly informed. Dis you try to use the full server path ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did

Comment: So verify that the file you are looking for is at the right place on the server ... After that, i can't help you more :s You can try to debug with `is_dir` or `file_exists` PHP functions ...

Comment: ok thanks. But I already verified that it exists.I keep on looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.
 Open the php.ini file and find the include_path line.
        . Add to the include_path the directory that you placed the 
            ZendGdata directory in. /your/directory/ZendGdata/library
        . Save and restart Apache
I hope it will be helpful for those who have the same problem